# Python multiprocessing is sharing cores

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using miltiprocessing to read a lot of chunks of a huge file and then process it, but I'm loosing something because sometimes when I launch some process, some of them share a core. Example: system with 12 cores, I run 10 process and 6 are en 6 cores (one with each) and other 4 are en 2 cores (2 in each core)... but other times, it works fine using 10 cores for 10 process...

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
[...]
process1=Process(target=run_thread, args=("./splited/"+file,result,))
process2=Process(target=run_thread, args=("./splited/"+file,result,))
process3=Process(target=run_thread, args=("./splited/"+file,result,))
process1.start() 
process2.start()
process3.start()
[...]
process1.join()
process2.join()
process3.join()
```

This is an example of my code, I was trying with 10 when I saw the issue.

Thanks.

EDITED:

- This machine works without multithread, so it has 12 cores with a maximum of 12 parallel threads.
- Sometimes there are more than 2 sharing a core.
- The neck of bottle is not the IO on this program it's process each line of the file.

Comment: Are you sure you want multiprocessing? Parallelization will only buy you performance gains for operations that are actually CPU-heavy. It won't help you at all with IO bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

I am certainly not an expert on this question, but it appears that most modern processsors actually are structured with physical cores and virtual cores. For example I have an Intel Core I7, which means I have 4 physical cores, but each of them actually contain 2 virtual cores, meaning that my processor can run 8 distinct processes in parallel.

You mention sometimes you have 2 processes per core, so that would be due to core virtualization.

By the way, if you aim at processing large amounts of data in smaller chunks, there is a specific module in python dedicated to such tasks: [Pool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), that is imported using

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

Hope this is useful to you,
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not the error, this server has multi-thread disabled (so only 12 threads simultaneous by 2 exa-core processor) and last time that I try, was 3 process on one processor, 2 in other and the others one by one.